# recreate a thread has lower latency than pause/resume thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt

I've recently written a vector graphic viewer using Qt.

There is a RenderThread runs in background to do the heavy rendering job.

An atomic flag is used to stop the rendering on processing next object.

In the main/gui thread, while an update is required:

1. the atomic flag is set;
2. wait until RenderThread actually stop;
3. apply the change and restart the rendering job.

I've tested 2 sync methods:

1. while RenderThread found the atomic flag set, it simply returns from the QThread::run() method, which makes the thread finished on QThread::wait();
2. using QWaitCondition, the RenderThread won't actually finish, and is put to wait on a mutex. The gui thread then locks this mutex to apply the change and unlock it before waking the RenderThread.

The problem is, there is observable slowerness for the second method, while the first method is more smooth. The difference is not big, just like playing 3d game on 50fps and  60fps.

Tested on:

- win7, I3 3220, 4gb ram
- win8, z3740d, 2gb ram

with qt4.8.6, msvc2008, and all gives similar result.

I've been always told creating a thread is expensive, but it appears not so in this case?

Comment: What are the numbers and what exactly did you measure? In any case, I suspect that if you create a thread, it is immediately scheduled to run, while a thread that was blocked is not immediately restarted when it is unblocked.

Comment: @Ulrich , well, I've measured the time for the "stop-wait-restart" procedure using QElapsedTimer in the main thread. But there is no explicit difference between 2 methods. So I can only say the difference is "observable".

Comment: Then use more precise measurement. If there is a difference it can be measured.